# Milter Application Error Postfix Email Server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, opendkim, milter

I am trying to sign the emails on my email server with opendkim but I am running against an error that I just can't seem to fix. The error I am getting is: `warning: milter local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: can't read SMFIC_BODY reply packet header: Application error`.

I have tried to set the `SOCKET` value to `inet:8891@localhost` (and 8892) in `/etc/opendkim.conf`, and set the value to `inet:127.0.0.1:8891` in the postfix config file. This did not help. I also tried to lower the `milter_protocol` but that did not help either.

I have tried several different variations of the legacy `etc/default/opendkim` file as well, but now I have everything commented out and it doesn't change a thing. The TCP/UDP port:53 is open in my firewall.

#### The relevant config files:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

```
# /etc/opendkim.conf
# This is a basic configuration for signing and verifying. It can easily be
# adapted to suit a basic installation. See opendkim.conf(5) and
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample for complete
# documentation of available configuration parameters.

# Log to syslog
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
LogWhy                  yes

# Common signing and verification parameters. In Debian, the "From" header is
# oversigned, because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems
# and thus somewhat security sensitive.
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              no
OversignHeaders         From

AutoRestart             yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1M
Background              yes
DNSTimeout              5
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256

# Signing domain, selector, and key (required). For example, perform signing
# for domain "example.com" with selector "2020" (2020._domainkey.example.com),
# using the private key stored in /etc/dkimkeys/example.private. More granular
# setup options can be found in /usr/share/doc/opendkim/README.opendkim.
#Domain                 example.com
#Selector               2020
#KeyFile                /etc/dkimkeys/example.private

# In Debian, opendkim runs as user "opendkim". A umask of 007 is required when
# using a local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-privileged
# user (for example, Postfix). You may need to add user "postfix" to group
# "opendkim" in that case.
UserID                  opendkim
UMask                   007

# Map domains in From address to keys used to sign messages
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table

# Hosts to ignore when verifying signatures
ExternalIgnoreList      /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

# A set of internal hosts whose mail should be signed
InternalHosts           /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

# Socket for the MTA connection (required). If the MTA is inside a chroot jail,
# it must be ensured that the socket is accessible. In Debian, Postfix runs in
# a chroot in /var/spool/postfix, therefore a Unix socket would have to be
# configured as shown on the last line below.
#Socket                 inet:8891@localhost
#Socket                 inet:8891
Socket                  local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock

PidFile                 /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

# Hosts for which to sign rather than verify, default is 127.0.0.1. See the
# OPERATION section of opendkim(8) for more information.
#InternalHosts          192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12

# The trust anchor enables DNSSEC. In Debian, the trust anchor file is provided
# by the package dns-root-data.
TrustAnchorFile         /usr/share/dns/root.key
#Nameservers            127.0.0.1
```

```
# /etc/default/opendkim --- legacy
# NOTE: This is a legacy configuration file. It is not used by the opendkim
# systemd service. Please use the corresponding configuration parameters in
# /etc/opendkim.conf instead.
#
# Previously, one would edit the default settings here, and then execute
# /lib/opendkim/opendkim.service.generate to generate systemd override files at
# /etc/systemd/system/opendkim.service.d/override.conf and
# /etc/tmpfiles.d/opendkim.conf. While this is still possible, it is now
# recommended to adjust the settings directly in /etc/opendkim.conf.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
# Change to /var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim to use a Unix socket with
# postfix in a chroot:
#RUNDIR=/var/spool/postfix/run/opendkim
#RUNDIR=/run/opendkim
#
# Uncomment to specify an alternate socket
# Note that setting this will override any Socket value in opendkim.conf
# default:
#SOCKET="local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock"

# listen on all interfaces on port 54321:
#SOCKET=inet:54321
# listen on loopback on port 12345:
#SOCKET=inet:8891@localhost
# listen on 192.0.2.1 on port 12345:
#SOCKET=inet:12345@192.0.2.1
#USER=opendkim
#GROUP=opendkim
#PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
#EXTRAAFTER=
```

What is causing this bug? Are there places where I haven't looked yet?

Comment: Extra info - when I change the SOCKET to `inet:8892@localhost`, opendkim does not show up when I run `netstat -l | grep opendkim`. Why does it not show up with this socket set up, but it does show up with the socket currently setup in my cf files?

Comment: Postfix is trying to connect to a UNIX domain socket: `warning: milter local:opendkim/opendkim.sock ...`. Instead, in /etc/postfix/main.cf configure Postfix to connect to your milter: `smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891`.

Comment: If I do that, my error becomes `warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused`. This is an error I had before, and I then was advised to change it back to how I used to have it originally (and how I have it in my example files)

Comment: Is opendkim running at all? `systemctl status opendkim`. It should be a service listening at port 8891.

Comment: @glts opendkim is active when I run `systemctl status`, however when I run `netstat -ano | grep 8891` I don't see opendkim listening there. Actually with this setup, opendkim is listening nowhere it seems. I don't get output when I run `netstat -l | grep opendkim`.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured opendkim to listen at 8891. Check that /etc/opendkim.conf has the setting `Socket inet:8891@localhost`.

Comment: It was configured already in that file. I also tried adding `inet:8891@127.0.0.1` to the `ExecStart` in the system file of opendkim, however when doing this the service wouldn't run at all.

Comment: When running `netstat -l | grep opendkim` on my original setup I get the following output: `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     569268   /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock`. I use this value in `/etc/opendkim.conf` and in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` so postfix should be able to reach this socket. I have also set up the right permissions. Is there anything else I could've missed?

Comment: `sudo opendkim -e Socket` should print the socket that we discussed above, `inet:8891@127.0.0.1`. Signing off.

Comment: It does print the right socket. Error I get now is `warning: milter inet:127.0.0.1:8891: can't read SMFIC_BODY reply packet header: Application error`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments:

```
warning: milter inet:127.0.0.1:8891: can't read SMFIC_BODY reply packet header: Application error
```

This means that Postfix can connect to port 8891. However, it does not receive a valid response.

So, *something* must be listening on port 8891. Though probably not a milter program.

Make sure that you configure your services consistently, port 8891 (or whatever) in Postfix’s configuration, in OpenDKIM’s configuration, and then check that an opendkim process does indeed start up properly and listen on port 8891. Check the logs.